# beautiful soup misses text when scraping html

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Here is a sample of my HTML. I need to parse all content for each record. This is one sample record.

```
<div class="list-group-item card-contact">
    <div class="card-base">
        <div class="card-name hot"><a href="contact.php?leaduuid=e888888e">ronald <b>loudia</b></a></div>
        <div class="card-last-seen"><i>Inquired:</i> 8 day ago, Value $205,000 Engaged </div>
    </div>
    <a class="card-expand" href="#"></a>
    <div class="card-mobile">
        <ul class="card-activities" data-score="27">
            <li class="card-update"><a class="btn" href="wrap.php?leaduuid=e888888e&amp;aid=0">Update</a></li>
            <li class="card-notes"><a class="btn" href="contact-notes.php?leaduuid=e888888e">Notes</a></li>
            <li class="card-email">
                <a class="btn" href="mailto:lou@ad.fr" title="leald@icloud.fr">
                    <div class="activity-label">Email:</div>
                    <div class="activity-value">lou@ad.fr</div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="card-sms"><a class="btn" href="sms:(222) 125-4444">SMS</a></li>
            <li class="card-phone">
                <a class="btn" href="tel:(222) 125-4444">
                    <div class="activity-label">Phone:</div>
                    <div class="activity-value">(222) 125-4444</div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get all the content between the tags.
Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import mechanize
import pandas as pd

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.open(url)
mylist = []
html_doc = br.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
mydivs = soup.find_all('div', ['card-name',
                               'card-last-seen',
                               'activity-value',
                               'card-activities',
                               'card-last-seen',
                               'activity-value',
                               'card-mobile'])
   
st = ''
for div in mydivs:
    if re.search('^\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)', div.text):
        st += f'{div.text}\n'
    else:
        st += f'{div.text}, '
mylist.append(st)
#print(mylist)

smallerlist = [l.split(', ') for l in ', '.join(mylist).split('\n')]
smallerlist
df = pd.DataFrame(smallerlist)
```

I only get some of the content, missing data-score and other content.

Not sure how to get both div and ul content.
Html has many records that I need to loop through and write to pandas DataFrame.

**The expected output in dataframe:**

```
FirstName   LastName    LastLogin   Value   Score   Email   sms phone-activity-Value
ronald  Lecloudia   8 day ago   $205,000 Engaged    27  lou@ad.fr   (222) 125-4444      (222) 125-4444
```

Comment: What data do you expect to see in your dataframe for the example HTML?

Comment: Added the expected output to the code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `data-score` attribute like this:

```
soup.ul.attrs['data-score']
```

Output:

```
'88888827'
```

More data:

```
import re

new_line_re = re.compile('\n{2,}')
new_line_re.sub('\n', soup.div.text).strip().split('\n')
```

Output:

```
['ronald Lecloudia',
 'Inquired: 888888 day ago, Value $205,000 Engaged ',
 'Update',
 'Notes',
 'Email:',
 'leald@icloud.fr',
 'SMS',
 'Phone:',
 '(232) 78888885-4444']
```

Comment: I need to get the data-score along with other data. Please see the expected output in the post. (just added)

Comment: Why is data-score missing? I can't figure out how to get the 'data-score' with other data?

Comment: @Stryker my first answer shows how to get `data-score`...`soup.ul.attrs['data-score']`

Comment: Where, which place do I add your code or replace my code to get both score and all other content for each record? Could you please show the final complete answer? I tried replacing part of the code with yours but still getting errors. Not sure where exactly I should place your code within my code. Thanks